# How to Auto-translate embedded videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-javascript-api

Quite simple.

If I use this code: https://www.youtube.com/embed/d0yGdNEWdn0?&hl=en&cc_lang_pref=en&cc_load_policy=1

With:

hl=en and cc_lang_pref=en to choose english
AND
cc_load_policy=1 to activate subs

It will work fine and show my subs in english.

The problem is, if I use portuguese: https://www.youtube.com/embed/d0yGdNEWdn0?&hl=pt&cc_lang_pref=pt&cc_load_policy=1

It will not work because there is no portuguese subtitles. However, you can use auto-translate and then have the portuguese subs as I wish.

The question is: how can I create a link that automatically activates the english>>portuguese translation? I have been look for it and didn't find an answer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: YouTube has still not implemented this possibility as of November 2022. One should request this feature.

Answer (score 3):

recently had the same question, but there is no clear answer for this.

**TL;DR: Just upload your PT translated subtitles with the same code in it.**

Your code for `pt` is correct. It's YouTube that not utilize your URL.

According to YT own logic - they give **auto-translated** subtitles full control only to a user (via clicking). And there are no ways to override it from the developer side (2019-04).

Same time you can add own subtitles on Portuguese. Even if they are translated from original English via Google Translate. And your code will start to work.

The Replies that gave me that info: https://support.google.com/youtube/forum/AAAAiuErobUTdcd8GOxOLE/?hl=en&gpf=%23!msg%2Fyoutube%2FTdcd8GOxOLE%2F9iVrU-qOc5YJ&msgid=9iVrU-qOc5YJ

Answer (score 2):

It seems this problem is not solved.
The community caption feature, which YouTube says was underutilized, has been discontinued in September.

So how to pass/force autotranslate in a youtube youtube.com/embed/ url ?

Community contributions going away soon
Community contributions will be discontinued across all channels after September 28, 2020. Community contributions allowed viewers to add closed captions, subtitles, and title/descriptions to videos. This feature was rarely used and had problems with spam/abuse so we’re removing them to focus on other creator tools. You can still use your own captions, automatic captions, and third-party tools and services. You have until September 28, 2020 to publish your community contributions before they’re removed.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6052538?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the owner can enable in Youtube editor, the option to add subtitles in different language.

Explained in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjCU0gr18g8

Then you can embed a: "`?cc_lang=`.." in the Link.